# Can I use more than two displays with a MacBook?

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook, thunderbolt

Is it possible to add more than two external displays to MacBook using the Thunderbolt interface only?  Would a chain of displays connected to each other on Thunderbolt work?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.apple.com/thunderbolt/), you can only use two Thunderbolt displays. However, [DisplayLink](http://www.displaylink.com/) has an [excellent USB display adapter](http://www.displaylink.com/shop/adapters).

Although your graphics processor may freak out on you, it should work just fine. Several people at my office use the DisplayLink adapters to push 2-3 displays from a MacBook Pro.